# Change url links on members loops in buddypress

Tags: urls, buddypress, list, members

I am new to buddypress, my installations is shown below.

WordPress version: 4.9.4

BuddyPress Version: 2.9.3.

I urgently need a way to change the url attached to members to link to member profile i.e. instead having
`http://www.example.com/members/member-name/` I’ll like it to be `http://www.example.com/members/member-name/profile`
Thanks

Comment: Rather than change the url, just change the default profile tab to 'profile': https://codex.buddypress.org/getting-started/guides/change-members-profile-landing-tab/